# LinqPad like operator error

Tags: sql, operator-keyword, sql-like, linqpad

I am new to linqpad and C#.
I wish to get the list of ids starting with "ic" in odata.
I tried SqlMethods.like and got this error. "The name 'SqlMethods' does not exist in the current context"

Below is the query

```
from id in Products

where SqlMethods.Like(id.ProductId, "IC%")

select id
```

please help. unable to find solution

Comment: Is your Language set to C# Statements? I ran something similar (in general syntax) and it works fine for me

Comment: No. I am using C# Expression. when i use C# statements i need to change the code to "var query = from id in Products where SqlMethods.Like(id.ProductId, "IC%") select id; Console.WriteLine(query);" and still get the same error

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have spelt SqlMethods **exactly** as in your example code?  And does it make any difference if you use the fully qualified name ie System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods ?

Comment: Yes i did speel that correctly and tried fully qualified name. the error that i have now is " Cannot execute text selection: 'System.Data' is a 'namespace', which is not valid in the given context

The name 'Linq' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: When you use an OData connection, LINQPad does NOT automatically import the "System.Data.Linq.* namespaces; hence the error. Of course, the SqlMethods class will not work with OData anyway, as people have pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData doesn't support Like operator. So even if you would get the above to compile it still wouldn't work correctly. If you just want to find all products who's id starts with IC you can use the StartsWith method:

```
from id in Products
where id.ProductId.StartsWith("IC")
select id;
```

Comment: I even tried that and it works partially. when I type IC-100 i retrieve data but when I just type IC i dont. It gives me error.

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using and the error you get (with a callstack)?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I aint using SqlMethods. I am using .StartsWith for my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the Contains method:

```
from id in Products
where id.ProductId.Contains("IC")
select id;
```

This will actually generate a LIKE statement in the SQL.